# How to sort AND limit Noe4j result using Gremlin?

Tags: sorting, graph, neo4j, gremlin

This is how you can sort (order) results from Neo4j graph using Gremlin:

```
g.v(id).out('knows').sort{it.name}
```

or

```
g.v(id).out('knows').sort{a,b -> a.name <=> b.name}
```

This is how to limit result using offset/skip and limit:

```
g.v(id).out('knows')[0..9]
```

However if you combine both sort and limit

```
g.v(id).out('knows').sort{it.name}[0..9]
```

it would throw an error...

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList$ListItr.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.lang.IntRange) values: [0..9]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(int), next(), mean(), set(java.lang.Object), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out that native Groovy methods like *sort* do not return Pipes, but iterators, iterables, etc. As such, to convert one of these objects back into a Pipeline flow you need to use **_()**:

```
g.v(id).out('knows').sort{it.name}._()[0..9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but with `except(sth).unique()` and limit `[0..5]` .
In my case:

ERROR:

```
except(xxx).unique()[0..5]
```

Works FINE:

```
except(sth).unique().findAll()[0..5]
```

Works FINE also with sort{}:

```
.unique().findAll().sort{it.sth}[0..5]
```

(Alexei Tenitski answer is good too)